# Ошибка: Error 1 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Fun
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
       {
           if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
       }
       else
       {
            MessageBox.Show("The box is not checked!");
       }
      }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

В Error лист вылезает ошибка:
Error   1   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Не могу понять, что не так? 
Он жалуется на класс
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged

Однако он написан правильно, и в полном порядке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас метод `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` находится уже вне класса. Удалите одну закрывающую фигурную скобку выше этого метода и добавьте ее ниже.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The box is not checked!");
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало.

Comment: @Klugge если помогло тут принято отмечать ответ как принятый

Comment: Cпасибо, а как ответ отметить как принятый? Не могу кнопочку найти...